# svelt how to implment mouse Hold and release

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte

I am working on svelt project that works like excel sheet and want to make selections work like excel spread sheet in which when i select on column header whole column get selected and hold and drag multiple headers if i want to select muliple columsn
here is code that implement this functunality

```
<SheetHeader>
  <SheetCell
    columnIdentifierKey={ID_ROW_CONTROL_COLUMN}
    isStatic
    isControlCell
    let:htmlAttributes
    let:style
  >
    <div {...htmlAttributes} {style} />
  </SheetCell>

  {#each [...$processedColumns] as [columnId, processedColumn] (columnId)}
    <SheetCell columnIdentifierKey={columnId} let:htmlAttributes let:style>
      <div {...htmlAttributes} {style}>
        <HeaderCell
          {processedColumn}
          isSelected={isColumnSelected(
            $selectedCells,
            $columnsSelectedWhenTheTableIsEmpty,
            processedColumn,
          )}
          on:mousedown={() => selection.onColumnSelectionStart(processedColumn)}
          on:mouseenter={() =>
            selection.onMouseEnterColumnHeaderWhileSelection(processedColumn)}
        />
        <SheetCellResizer columnIdentifierKey={columnId} />
        <ContextMenu>
          <ColumnHeaderContextMenu {processedColumn} />
        </ContextMenu>
      </div>
    </SheetCell>
  {/each}

  {#if hasNewColumnButton}
    <SheetCell
      columnIdentifierKey={ID_ADD_NEW_COLUMN}
      let:htmlAttributes
      let:style
    >
      <div {...htmlAttributes} class="new-column-cell" {style}>
        <NewColumnCell />
      </div>
    </SheetCell>
  {/if}
</SheetHeader>
```

now the problem is when i drag from below sheet grids till header the `mouseenter` event gets activated and selects whole column insted of just some gird part.
now i want to work it such that when i am using the mousedown for spread sheet mouseenter event should not trigger in this function and sugestions? how can i fix this functuniality?

solution or suggestions to how can i fix the issue

Comment: Maybe use a flag like `selectingColumns` that is set to `true` in `on:mousedown` on a column and the `on:mouseenter` callback directly returns if it isn't `true` (reset to `false` in window on:mouseup event)